# Myeclipse trial version is not running my phonegap on my windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: myeclipse

I have just downloaded the following node.js x64 bit, phonegap win32.exe and myeclipse and selected the 30 day trail. Selected the General tab and selected mobile but it does not show phonegap. Is there a step I missed out on the installation or do I need to download node.js 32 bit version cause the phonegap desktop app says win32.I would like use Myeclipse to run phonegap projects.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you downloaded the latest release (2016 CI 0). If so, please see this forum entry, which explains the missing [PhoneGap Tooling in MyEclipse 2016](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/phonegap-tooling-in-myeclipse-2016/).

To continue to have the PhoneGap tooling, you need to download MyEclipse 2015, for now.